# Kivy ActionBar back Button to switch to previous screen

Tags: python, android-actionbar, kivy

I am trying to run this type of code on android but when i tap mobile back button, inspite of coming to the previous screen app is closed,
i used this piece of code to stop the App for being closed:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.BackButton)


def BackButton(self, window, key, *args):
    if key==27:
        return True
```

But how to return to the previous screen. and how to use ActionPrevious Button to come at previous screen?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<MyAppGUI>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    id: box
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'How to go back using this button???'
                with_previous: True

    ScreenManager:
        id: screenmanger
        Screen:
            name: 's1'
            Button:
                text: 'goto screen 2'
                on_release: screenmanger.current='s2'
        Screen:
            name: 's2'
            Button:
                text: 'goto screen 3'
                on_release: screenmanger.current='s3'
        Screen:
            name: 's3'
            Button:
                text: 'goto main screen'
                on_release: screenmanger.current='s1'




""")

class MyAppGUI(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyAppGUI()


if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

To return to the previous window using `ActionPrevious` button you just need to bind its `on_release` event to a function that uses `current` property to set the previous screen using the name returned by `ScreenManager.previous ()` method or use a list that serves as a history of the windows visited. To use the <kbd>Back</kbd> key on Android, your code is correct in principle, at least on my device it works without problems:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout



Builder.load_string("""
<MyAppGUI>:
    sm: screenmanger
    orientation:'vertical'
    id: box
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'How to go back using this button???'
                with_previous: True
                on_release: root.set_previous_screen() 

    ScreenManager:
        id: screenmanger
        Screen:
            name: 's1'
            Button:
                text: 'goto screen 2'
                on_release:
                    screenmanger.transition.direction = 'right'
                    screenmanger.current='s2'
        Screen:
            name: 's2'
            Button:
                text: 'goto screen 3'
                on_release:
                    screenmanger.transition.direction = 'right'
                    screenmanger.current='s3'
        Screen:
            name: 's3'
            Button:
                text: 'goto main screen'
                on_release:
                    screenmanger.transition.direction = 'right'
                    screenmanger.current='s1'
""")


class MyAppGUI(BoxLayout):
    sm = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyAppGUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self._key_handler)

    def _key_handler(self, instance, key, *args):
        if key is 27:
            self.set_previous_screen()
            return True

    def set_previous_screen(self):
        if self.sm.current != 's1':
            self.sm.transition.direction = 'left'
            self.sm.current = self.sm.previous()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyAppGUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: How to get the previous screen option on a button(in normal desktop application)?